# Unit Test Principle in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am learning unit test in Rails framework. I have a question about controller test.

```
**assert_select '#columns #side a', minimum: 4**
```

Does this line of code mean to  simulate that a user visit the page and checkout whether there are four a tags? I am confused about this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, it checks there are 4 or more `a` tags, within a `#columns #side` element - that is, the CSS selector `#columns #side a` would have 4 or more matches. See the examples at this page: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select

and further examples at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views

Comment: But why it is a controller test rather than a view test?

Comment: Ideally it probably should be in the view test. However, many controller actions will return a view. So, when testing a controller, you're able to test the view it returns in the same step.

Comment: Is it like that controller as a pile  view as liquid? The controller tests will test all the views(as texts) through the controller. Is it right?

Comment: "controller as a pile view as liquid" - haven't heard that one before. But yes, the views will be tested through the controller.

Comment: It is very nice of you. I mean before the view texts are sent to browser they must be through the controller.

Comment: Oh, controller as a pipe, and view as liquid? That makes more sense - though it's still not totally accurate.